# How to convert my many if statements into switch statements? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am very new to JavaScript so I apologise if this is a ridiculous question.

Here is my code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!rule1') {
        message.channel.send('Rule 1: **Don\'t be annoying.**');
    }
    if (message.content === '!rule2') {
        message.channel.send('Rule 2: **Leaving the server during your crypt sentence will result in a permanent ban. 3 strikes and you\'re out.**');
    }
    if (message.content === '!rule3') {
        message.channel.send('Rule 3: **Watch your language.**');
    }
    if (message.content === '!rule4') {
        message.channel.send('Rule 4: **No NSFW content of any kind.**');
    }
    if (message.content === '!rule5') {
        message.channel.send('Rule 5: **No racism, homophobia, or other hate speech is allowed whatsoever.**');
    }
    if (message.content === '!rule6') {
        message.channel.send('Rule 6: **Moderators\' discretion.**');
    }
    if (message.content === '!rule7') {
        message.channel.send('Rule 7: **Don\'t randomly ping roles or people for no reason.**');
    }
    if (message.content === '!rule8') {
        message.channel.send('Rule 8: **No spam allowed whatsoever.** Spam will result in a delete and warn, and a crypt sentence if continued.');
    }
    if (message.content === '!rule9') {
        message.channel.send('Rule 9: Please speak English at all times! Non-English messages are subject to deletion.');
    }
    if (message.content === '!rule10') {
        message.channel.send('Rule 10: **Please avoid talking about triggering topics.**');
    }
    if (message.content === '!rule11') {
        message.channel.send('Rule 11: **Please censor all personally identifiable info from images and text.**');
    }
    if (message.content === '!rule12') {
        message.channel.send('Rule 12: **Please keep bot commands in <#620789282226962464>**.');
    }
    if (message.content === '!rule13') {
        message.channel.send('Rule 13: **Posting gore is an instant deletion of your message(s) and permanent ban.**');
    }
    if (message.content === '!rule14') {
        message.channel.send('Rule 14: **YOU MUST BE 13 YEARS OF AGE OR OLDER TO USE THIS SERVER.**');
    }
    if (message.content === '!rule15') {
        message.channel.send('Rule 15: **Politics are strictly banned from the server.**');
    }
    if (message.content === '!rule16') {
        message.channel.send('Rule 16: **Don\'t name yourself stupid things.**');
    }
    if (message.content === '!rule17') {
        message.channel.send('Rule 17: **No bright flashing media of any kind, including emotes.**');
    }
    if (message.content === '!rule18') {
        message.channel.send('Rule 18: **No Gacha edits.**');
    }
    if (message.content === '!rule19') {
        message.channel.send('Rule 19: **Keep conversation civil and appropriate.**');
    }
    if (message.content === '!rule20') {
        message.channel.send('Rule 20: **No edgy, dark or offensive jokes or memes.**');
    }
    if (message.content === '!rule21') {
        message.channel.send('Rule 21: **No threats or considerations of ||self-harm|| or ||suicide|| in the server.**');
    }
    if (message.content === '!rule22') {
        message.channel.send('Rule 22: **Anything that violates Discord TOS will get you immediately banned.**');
    }
    if (message.content === '!rule23') {
        message.channel.send('Rule 23: **Do not sexualize/ship any of the moderators, or any members of the server for that matter.**');
    }
    if (message.content === '!strikeappeal') {
        message.channel.send('If you would like to appeal a strike, you can DM <@738765589748645908>. Simply explain why you got that strike, why you think it should be removed, and apologize.');
    }
});
```

I think you can agree with me when I say that this code looks very long and messy. Is there any way I can shorten this code? I can't figure out how to convert it into something like switch statements. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Use an object or a Map: `const rules = { "!rule1": "...", "!rule2": "...", ... };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
client.on('message', message => {
    switch (message.content) {
      case '!rule1': 
          message.channel.send('Rule 1: **Don\'t be annoying.**');
          break;
      case '!rule2':
          message.channel.send('Rule 2: **Leaving the server during your crypt sentence will result in a permanent ban. 3 strikes and you\'re out.**');
          break;
      case '!rule3':
            message.channel.send('Rule 3: **Watch your language.**');
        break;
      case '!strikeappeal':
          message.channel.send('If you would like to appeal a strike, you can DM <@738765589748645908>. Simply explain why you got that strike, why you think it should be removed, and apologize.');
          break;
        
      ...
      
      default:
            message.channel.send('Default message');
   }
});
```

**Remark:** Don't forget the break at the end of a case because otherwise the next case will be executed too.

Comment: Thank you, this example helped me understand the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

As @Andreas suggested, put your rules in an object and then have some general purpose code to pull out the appropriate rule.

```js
const rules = {
  '!rule1': 'Rule 1: **Don\'t be annoying.**',
  '!rule2': 'Rule 2: **Leaving the server during your crypt sentence will result in a permanent ban. 3 strikes and you\'re out.**'
};
// etc

client.on('message', message => {
  const ruleText = rules[message.content];
  if (ruleText) {
    message.channel.send(ruleText);
  } else {
    // normal message
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

1. change all the `if` statements (except the first) into `else if`
   This is almost the same as a switch and takes minimal adjustments
2. read on how a switch statement works [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to reduce repeated parts and make it easier to make new commands and add new rules. However, instead of typing something like `!rule3`, you have to type `!rule 3`.

For more information on how to extend your bot, read the [Discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/).

```js
const prefix = '!';

const rules = [
    "**Don\'t be annoying.**",
    "**Leaving the server during your crypt sentence will result in a permanent ban. 3 strikes and you\'re out.**",
    "**Watch your language.**",
    "**No NSFW content of any kind.**",
    "**No racism, homophobia, or other hate speech is allowed whatsoever.**",
    "**Moderators\' discretion.**",
    "**Don\'t randomly ping roles or people for no reason.**",
    "**No spam allowed whatsoever.** Spam will result in a delete and warn, and a crypt sentence if continued.",
    "**Please speak English at all times! Non-English messages are subject to deletion.**",
    "**Please avoid talking about triggering topics.**",
    "**Please censor all personally identifiable info from images and text.**",
    "**Please keep bot commands in <#620789282226962464>.**",
    "**Posting gore is an instant deletion of your message(s) and permanent ban.**",
    "**YOU MUST BE 13 YEARS OF AGE OR OLDER TO USE THIS SERVER.**",
    "**Politics are strictly banned from the server.**",
    "**Don\'t name yourself stupid things.**",
    "**No bright flashing media of any kind, including emotes.**",
    "**No Gacha edits.**",
    "**Keep conversation civil and appropriate.**",
    "**No edgy, dark or offensive jokes or memes.**",
    "**No threats or considerations of ||self-harm|| or ||suicide|| in the server.**",
    "**Anything that violates Discord TOS will get you immediately banned.**",
    "**Do not sexualize/ship any of the moderators, or any members of the server for that matter.**"
];

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/\s+/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowercase();

    switch (command) {
        case 'rule':
            if (!args[0]) return message.reply('**usage:** `!rule <rule number>`.');

            args[0] = Number(args[0]);
            if (!(args[0] > 0 && args[0] <= rules.length)) return message.reply(`please enter a number between 1 and ${rules.length}.`);

            message.channel.send(`Rule ${args[0]}: ${rules[args[0] - 1]}`);
            break;
        case 'strikeappeal':
            message.channel.send('If you would like to appeal a strike, you can DM <@738765589748645908>. Simply explain why you got that strike, why you think it should be removed, and apologize.');
            break;
        default:
            message.reply(`the command \`${command}\` was not recognized.`);
});
```